# How can I run queries in TinkerGraph using query strings?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkergraph

I want to run some queries in TinkerGraph, but I need to read them from an external text file, instead of performing Java calls:

```
TinkerGraph graph = TinkerGraph.open();
GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();


InputStream input = new FileInputStream("graph.json");
GraphSONReader reader = GraphSONReader.build().create();
reader.readGraph(input, graph);

// Something like
run("g.V().hasLabel("foo").."
```

I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254378/get-gremlin-query-as-a-string-and-execute-it-in-java-without-submitting-it-to-th) but the answers show some solutions using ConcurrentBindings that are not very clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GremlinGroovyScriptEngine` class to perform the evaluation of a text string query, while using embedded TinkerGraph. If working with a Gremlin Server you would not need to do this.

The example below should more or less work unchanged. You may need to add a few `include` and type declaration statements from Java code but the basic building blocks essentially are these:

```java
ScriptEngine engine = new GremlinGroovyScriptEngine(); 
Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings(); 
bindings.put("g", graph.traversal()); 
engine.eval("g.V().limit(5)", bindings);
```

Comment: Do I need to download any other JARs? I'm getting: 

error: package org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223 does not exist

Although, gremlin-groovy package exists in the classpath.

Comment: On my system that has the Gremlin Console at the 3.6.2 level installed, the file is in the `gremlin-groovy-3.6.2.jar` file.